Gapless excitations in strongly coupled systems
I need help finding the right reference material to study.  I want to understand what gapless excitations mean, what Goldstone modes are, and what the difference is between gapped and gapless superfluids and superconductors. Also, what their dispersion relations or spectral density look like.
I also want to understand what papers mean when they say that in strongly coupled systems, the dispersion relation has branch cuts instead of poles.
What would be good material to learn these things?
